# SQL query returns invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using this query string:

```
SELECT 
    requires, level 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         requires, level, 
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY level ORDER BY z_index) rn 
     FROM " & DBTABLE & " 
     WHERE ProductID = '" & ProductID & "') A 
WHERE 
     rn = 1
```

Returns

> Invalid column name 'z_index'

on customer's server but works fine on my server.

Would different versions of SQL Server handle this query differently?

**Update**: I should also mention the 'z_index' column has no trouble working in other queries that I am using. It's just this particular query that has trouble with it.

Comment: It sounds like a schema mismatch between the two databases.  Make sure they both have column "z_index" defined!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: there might be differences between versions of databases, some databases reserve keywordlike words and dont allow you to use them as column names. Those reservations might change per version. I would dump the schema or "describe table" or something to compare the tables

Comment: Tag the database you are using (for both instances - what you call "my server" and "customers" server ), including version of both, and including schemas.

Comment: the simplest way to assure that column exist at your client side is running the query: `select top 1 z_index from DBTABLE` at your client instance

Comment: I hope that you are protecting against sql injection in another fashion since you aren't using parameters.